# Keyhole integral and version of $\log$ in $\frac{\log t}{(t^2+1)^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms

I want to calculate $$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\log t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$

It certainly looks like a contour integral. I'm thinking about the keyhole contour where the "hole" is around the origin and along the positive $x$-axis. Along the horizontal line above the $x$-axis, it is our desired integral. But what should it be along the horizontal line *below* the $x$-axis? I'm not so well-versed with versioning of $\log$ to say this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the real axis, you would get $\log t + 2\pi i$ from the branch of the logarithm, so in the integral

$$\int_C \frac{\log z}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz$$

the $\log t$ parts cancel, and you are left with

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)^2} = -\sum \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\log z}{(z^2+1)^2};\zeta\right).$$

To evaluate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log t}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt$$

with that keyhole contour, you need to consider

$$\int_C \frac{(\log z)^2}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz,$$

as the integrals over the parts above and below the real axis combine to

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(\log t)^2 - (\log t + 2\pi i)^2}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt = -4\pi i \int_0^\infty \frac{\log t}{(t^2+1)^2}\,dt + 4\pi^2\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2+1)^2}.$$